# NAs introduits lors de la conversion automatique

Tags: r

I'm presently learning R and I'm suppose to do a knn model on my dataset

[image]

I've tested this but that doesn't work at all.

```
 predKNN = knn(app[,1:19], test[,1:19],test[,20], k = 3)
```

I get the following error

```
NAs introduced during the automatic conversion
```

Comment: Please provide the error message in english. With KNN do you mean this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm ?

Comment: @FlorianSchunke yes K-nearest neighbors algorithm: KNN